# Accidentally deleted sites/all/modules in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, backups

Let's say I was having a really rough day and I accidentally deleted the sites/all/modules directory in Drupal 7. Could I simply unzip my last back up of Drupal and copy that directory over to the server? Are there any other considerations or steps I should do and if this won't work, how should I go about fixing it? Thanks!

Running Drupal 7.50

Comment: While you are at it, might as well upgrade Drupal. As 7.52 **fixed security vulnerabilities**, so you should upgrade your Drupal to the latest version, which is [7.53](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal) as of this writing.

Comment: Will do, that's next on my agenda after I complete this long and complicated CRM upgrade.

Comment: Do you have version controlling like git or anything? If yes, then get your last comitted code through checking out previous head reference. Instance, git reset --hard HEAD-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the backup files you have are the same as the ones that were deleted, that should be fine.

You'll probably want to flush the cache but other than that there shouldn't be any problems in theory.

Comment: Thank you Clive, I appreciate it. We'll see how it goes!

Comment: Good luck! And get some version control going ;)

Comment: I'm in the process if implementing and using GIT. Thanks!